# Expecting functions to be invoked with functions as parameters

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, jasmine

I have a fairly straightforward set of specs for a backbone view:

```
describe 'Avia.MatricesView', ->

  beforeEach ->
    @model = {
      bind: ->
      fetch: ->
    }
    spyOn(Avia, 'Matrices').andReturn(@model)
    @matricesView = new Avia.AviaView(addFixtureDiv('fixture'))

  describe 'initialization', ->

    beforeEach ->
      spyOn(@model, 'bind')
      spyOn(@model, 'fetch')
      @matricesView.initialize()

    it 'creates a new Matrices model', ->
      expect(Avia.Matrices).toHaveBeenCalledOnce()

    it 'binds the model change event to render', ->
      expect(@model.bind).toHaveBeenCalledWith('change', @matricesView.render)

    it 'fetches the model data', ->
      expect(@model.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(success: @matricesView.render, error: @matricesView.showError)
```

The MatricesView does just as the spec expects:

```
initialize: =>
  @model = new Avia.Matrices()
  @model.bind('change', @render)
  @model.fetch(success: @render, error: @showError)

showError: =>
  alert('An error occurred while fetching data from the server.')

render: =>
  html = JST['views/matrices_view_template']()
  @el.html(html)
```

The expectation that a new Matrices model is being created passes.  The other two specs fail, though, in ways that confuse me:

```
Avia.MatricesView initialization binds the model change event to render. (/home/duncan/avia/spec/javascripts/views/matrices_view_spec.js.coffee:21)
  Expected spy bind to have been called with [ 'change', Function ] but was called with [ [ 'change', Function ] ] (line ~22)
    expect(this.model.bind).toHaveBeenCalledWith('change', this.matricesView.render);

Avia.MatricesView initialization fetches the model data. (/home/duncan/avia/spec/javascripts/views/matrices_view_spec.js.coffee:24)
  Expected spy fetch to have been called with [ { success : Function, error : undefined } ] but was called with [ [ { success : Function, error : Function } ] ] (line ~25)
    expect(this.model.fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
```

As far as I can tell, Jasmine thinks that the function returned by `@matricesView.render` in the scope of the spec is different to the function returned by `@render` in the scope of the   instance of the MatricesView.

Also, I completely fail to understand why `@matricesView.showError` is undefined when it's clearly defined in MatricesView.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I definitely need a second pair of eyes on this as mine are a bit weary right now :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I'm *really* embarrassed now.  Looking at this with a fresh pair of eyes in the morning:

```
@matricesView = new Avia.AviaView(addFixtureDiv('fixture'))
```

... should have been ...

```
@matricesView = new Avia.MatricesView(addFixtureDiv('fixture'))
```

The test *should* have been failing, as I was actually testing the wrong class.

o_O

Comment: Haha, I've been looking for an answer for this for most of today and also didn't spot it! Well done mate, thanks for updating the question

Answer (score 0):

The first failed test seems to be related to this issue: https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/issues/45 Try wrapping your arguments in an array:

```
expect(@model.bind).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['change', @matricesView.render])
```

The second one is more baffling—there's no way `@matricesView.showError` is undefined (and you could throw in a `console.log` to confirm this). So that's probably just a stringification problem; try producing a simplified test case and posting to the Jasmine issue tracker. But as far as getting the test to pass, try the array wrapping. If that doesn't work, could it be that Jasmine is testing for reference equality rather than deep object equality? If that's the case, you might want to try the recently-added [objectContaining](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/pull/100) matcher.